# Highlight rows when all values are for Order Number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting, cell-format

I have a spreadsheet with two columns. One column is Order Number and the other one shows its status. As shown in the screenshot below:
Sample Data Sheet:
[image: Sample Data Sheet]

I want to highlight all the rows when the status for an order number is true for all its rows, if even on is false then the row is not highlighted. Please see the screenshot of the output below:

Output:
[image: Output]

By using conditional formatting I could get the output for a single id and status but here the number of ORDER ID changes for each I am not sure how to place a check for that.

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! Why is the first S003 green?

Comment: thank you for pointing this out it should not be green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Orders are on column A and Statuses are on column B.

- Select the orders
- Click on Conditional Formatting, then New Rule.
- Click on "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". Enter the following formula:

```
=AND(INDEX(FILTER($A$2:$B$23,$A$2:$A$23=A2),,2))
```

- Click on Format, select the desired color. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

**Caveat:** The formula works for Excel 365 not Excel 2016.

[image]

Comment: Thank You it is working as I needed, I tried on ms excel 2019 but not working there also so I think should get the output there on 365.

Comment: @zainulabidin a word of caution…  be careful to limit your use of complex formula for conditional formatting to be the minimum necessary.  In my experience, accidental circular references or logic errors in conditional formatting formulas has been the single largest cause of sheet corruption.  I’m not saying that you shouldn’t do it when needed, just seek the most conservative formulas when you do.